# Calling a URL from an MFC - MDI application Pin

Tags: mfc

I have a simple `MDI` application which will load a browser view in its child frame. For an instance I am loading `gmail` in the child frame.

I am using `CHtmlView` class and the function `CHtmlView::Navigate2` to do the same. I have no issues in opening the link. As per my knowledge, this need IE browser right? What If I want to use chrome and do the same?

Answer (score 3):

The `CHtmlView` is just a wrapper around `IWebBrowser2` COM control that is hosted in IE. You will not be able to change it to use other web rendering engines.

Comment: In case if I override the oncreate function with the CLSID_MozillaBrowse, will I be able to do that?

Comment: I'd suggest creating your own class wrapper or use existing one for `CLSID_MozillaBrowse`

Comment: Can you please help me with getting CLSID_MozillaBrowse ? It will be browser version dependent or it will be a static value?